# installation packages via anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to install some software using anaconda installed on ubuntu

```
conda install -c conda-forge numpy scipy rdkit
```

for which I have constant message and nothing happens:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
```

i've already tried to resolved it via

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```

Comment: did you activate the conda env?

Comment: yes, i did :--)

Comment: did you try to update conda? `conda update conda`

Comment: yes, I've just made it. the update passed OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe following this Anaconda's references : https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy

```
conda create --name MYENV python=3.9
conda activate MYENV

conda install -c anaconda numpy 
conda install -c anaconda scipy 
conda install -c rdkit rdkit
```

otherwise maybe use `pip`.

Comment: thanks! but anyway if I do not want to install the packages in the special invironment (--name MYENV) I may skip the first line, right ? I've just installed another package using conda install prody (without the definition of the channel and it worked well so ..

Comment: Then, you would want to skip the two first lines. Installing packages outside of user-created envs is not really a good habit. If you want to switch to another env you probably have created before : ```conda activate MY_OLDER_ENV_NAME``` and conda install the packages you need.

Comment: right thank you! anyway installation still does not work, I see always the message Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Comment: Maybe you can start and work on a fresh new env or uninstall conda completly and install it again. I'm not quite sure of which env you are using nor what commands you did before things broke down.

Comment: actually I just installed it on completely fresh Ubuntu system so besides of the commands indicated in the first message I did nothing. I believe I am using very up-to-date version btw:  conda 4.11.0

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to install packages incrementally - it's a waste of computation/energy. Instead, include all the packages in the `create` command. Also, the **conda-forge** channel now actively maintains `rdkit` builds, whereas the **rdkit** channel does not. In summary, a better command is: `conda create -n MYENV -c conda-forge python=3.9 scipy rdkit`

Comment: In fact I've done like this as well and got the message about the conflicts. I suppose it might be due to the version of rdkit which has not been tested with python 3.9, which is being used by conda. Here is the error: Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.